# Ember JS - Update property on all instances of a component

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Is it possible to update a property on all instances of a component?

If I have 10 instances of the component below on a page, I would like to set the currentTrack property to false on all of them. Is this possible? Can it be done from inside one of the components?

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({

    currentTrack: true,

});
```

I'm using Ember 2.12

Comment: You'll have to roll this yourself, I think. In the `init` hook, "register" the instance in a global array or something. Then provide a class-level method which goes through them all and does whatever you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Ember.Evented](https://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Evented.html) for this use case.

Here, there is a [simple twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/c05f1f58fc46c291b3078259f91ded1c?openFiles=components.my-component.js) for it.

Answer (score 0):

template.hbs

```
{{your-component-name currentTrack=currentTrack}}
{{your-component-name currentTrack=currentTrack}}
{{your-component-name currentTrack=currentTrack}}
// btn for disabling 
<a href="#" class="btn" onclick={{action 'makeAllcurrentTracksFalse'}}>To false</a>
```

controller.js

```
currentTrack: true,
actions: {
    makeAllcurrentTracksFalse() {this.set('currentTrack', false)}
}
```

**or in your-component-name.js - you can use the same action as above and it will be applied to all components**

Answer (score 0):

How about you create entries for what ever thing your're trying to achieve.

```
const SongEntry = Ember.Object.extend({ 

});
```

To create an entry you would call (probably add a song to playlist?)

```
  songs: [],

  addNewSongToList: function(songName) {
       const newEntry = MyMusicEntry.create({
           isCurrent: false,
           title: songName
       });

       this.get('songs').pushObject(newEntry);
  },

  activateNewSong: function(newSongToActivate) {
     this.get('songs').forEach(s => s.set('isCurrent', false);

     newSongToActivate.set('isCurrent', true)
  }
```

Template would look like this

```
 {{each songs as |song|}}
     {{my-song-component songEntry=song changeSong=(action "activateNewSong")}}
 {{/each}}
```

*//my-song-component.js*

```
<div class="song-layout" {{action "changeSong" song}}>
```